# Abstract algebra, prove that $(a^m)^n$ =$ a^{mn}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $a$ be an element of group $G$. For any integers $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ ($m,n$ can be positive and negative). Prove that $(a^{m})^{n}=a^{mn}$, then show that $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$ by using what we proved so far.

So far we proved:

1. the Cancellation law: for $a,b,c$ are 3 elements in group $G$, then: $ab=ac$ implies $b=c$ and $ba=ca$ implies $b=c$.
2. $ab=ca$ implies that $b=c$ for $a,b,c \in G$.
3. If $ab=e$, then $b=a^{-1}$ for $a,b$ in group $G$, $e$ is an identity element.
4. We proved the sock-shoe property: If $G$ is a group and $a,b,c$ are elements, then
   $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1} a^{-1}$.
5. Next we showed that
   $(a^{n})^{-1}=(a^{-1})^{n}$ for $(a^{n})^{-1}$ is the inverse of $a^{n}$ and $(a^{-1})^{n}$
   is the multiplication of n copies of $a^{-1}$.

I don't know how to use all of then for the task I'm doing. What I am thinking is separate the task into 4 pieces:($m,n >0$), ($m>0, n<0$), ($m<0, n>0$), ($m,n<0$) and do it one by one.
And this is what I did for the first part ($m,n >0$):

$a^m= a.a.a.a.......a$ ($m$ times)

$(a^m)^n = [(a.a.a....a).(a.a.a...a)....(a.a.a...a)]$ $n$ times.

Open the (), we have $a.a.a.a....a.....a.....a$ for ($mn$ times)

so at the end, we have $(a^m)^n = a^{mn}$

Is my way to prove it good or not, any suggestion for the rest of these parts, please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Try inducting on $n$ instead.

Comment: I think I tried the induction for the left hand site by expanding it, then re-group it again to get $a^{mn}$, but for m and n negative, I dont know to to expand them.

Comment: For $m<0$ you can use property 5 to replace $a$ by $a^{-1}$, so you really only have two cases ($n>0$, $n<0$).

Comment: I can work when $m<0. n>0$, but I'm stuck when $n<0$ because I dont know how to expand like what I did above.

Answer (score 4):

Let's prove the claim first for natural $m$ and $n$ (that is, $m\ge0$ and $n\ge0$) by induction on $n$.

The base case, $n=0$, is easily settled: $(a^m)^0=1=a^{m0}$. So, assume it holds for $n$; then
\begin{align}
(a^m)^{n+1}&=(a^m)^n\cdot a^m &&\text{definition of powers}\\
&=a^{mn}\cdot a^m &&\text{induction hypothesis}\\
&=a^{mn+m} &&\text{property of powers}\\
&=a^{m(n+1)} &&\text{distributive property}
\end{align}

Here we assume that $a^{r+s}=a^r\cdot a^s$ has already been proved.

Now we turn to the case where $m\ge0$ and $n<0$; we'll use the fact that $b^n=(b^{-1})^{-n}$ for any integer $n$ (which can be proved easily); so
\begin{align}
(a^m)^n&=((a^m)^{-1})^{-n}\\
&=((a^{-1})^{m})^{-n}\\
&=(a^{-1})^{-mn}\\
&=a^{-(-mn)}\\
&=a^{mn}
\end{align}

The cases $m<0$, $n\ge0$ and $m<0$, $n<0$ can be proved similarly.